# ClearCase: User Roles

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

According to the [ClearCase UCM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_ucm_process.htm) there are follwoing roles for UCM users:

- administrator
- project manager
- developer
- release builder

Are these just conceptual roles or they are actually defined in the ClearCase database with assigned privilages and users can belong to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

ClearCase has no applicative role.
ClearCase has no applicative users.

I.e. you cannot define a user and associate him/her to a role (role that you cannot define either).
And that is a *major* limitation, as you have to rely on system-based definition for the:

- user (they need to be registered in the right unix or windows group, because ClearCase base its protection mechanism on the OS ACL)
- role: you have only two: privileged user (on Windows, a user who is in the same group than the `clearcase_albd` process, and on Unix... root!). And all the other (non-privileged) users.
  See [Privileged users and groups](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_access_usr_grp_privileged.htm) and [Domain user and group accounts](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_domainadm_accounts.htm) for more.